# MongoDB Doctrine ODM Query Builder equals vs reference

Tags: php, mongodb, symfony, doctrine-odm

Can anyone tell me the difference of the MongoDB Doctrine ODM Querybuilder functions equals and references used to for a collection record reference. Consider the following sample code to fetch the blogs belonging to a user reference stored in the variable $user. I can use both equals() and the refereneces() to get the result. So what is their difference in this scenerio? Does one has more advantages over the other?

```
$query = $dm->createQueryBuilder('AppBundle:Blogs')
            ->field('user')->references($user)
            ...
         ;
```

VS

```
$query = $dm->createQueryBuilder('AppBundle:Blogs')
            ->field('user')->equals($user)
            ...
         ;
```

Answer (score 0):

The `equals` version works probably because the ODM can sees that the `user` field is a reference and will do its best to help you. Personally I wouldn't rely on this too much, if you know the field you're querying holds a reference just use `->references()`.